# Force the keyboard to become visible and stay visible in view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitextfield

I want to have the virtual keyboard appear in my view on load and I want it to say visible for the lifetime of the view. There is a text field and I treat as the primary control for this view.

Initially, I called `[self.textField becomeFirstResponder]` in `-viewWillAppear:` following advice I've gotten here. Then, I came up with a different idea: I overloaded UIViewController's `-becomeFirstResponder`.

```
- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder
{
    if (self.primeResponder)
        return [self.primeResponder becomeFirstResponder];
    return [super becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I'm not seeing any hidden problems with this, but then again, no one recommends it either. Am I missing something? Is this a bad approach? Please help.

Comment: What you could do is overload the textfield's delegate methods so that they do not automatically call [self resignFirstResponder]. If you overload them then the keyboard will stay up forever until you tell it to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reviewing my old question, I thought now would be a good time provide an answer to this.

It works and does not have any major drawbacks.

I've had good luck with this method except in a peculiar circumstance. I used this to set a text field in a table view cell as the prime responder. In iOS 6, it didn't load the keyboard or highlight the textfield when the view was pushed onto the navigation controller stack.

See [In iOS 6, -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] doesn't work in -viewWillAppear:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479997/in-ios-6-uitextfield-becomefirstresponder-doesnt-work-in-viewwillappear) for my solution to that problem.