# getting becomeFirstResponder to call without user tapping UITextView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextview, becomefirstresponder

I would like the keyboard to appear automatically when a certain `UITextView` appears.  Right now, the first time the `UITextView` appears, the user has to tap on it for the keyboard to appear.  Subsequent appearances of the `UITextView` automatically make the keyboard appear.  How can I make this happen the first time the `UITextView` appears as well?

```
-(void)displayComposeScreen
{
    [self.nameField resignFirstResponder]; //This is a different UITextView, but my issue doesn't change whether I leave this line in or take it out

    if (!self.textView)
    {
        self.textView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 20, 280, 150)]; //This is the UITextView with whose appearance I want the keyboard to appear automatically.
        self.textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:14];
        self.textView.delegate = self;
    }
    [self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
    self.textView.hidden=NO;
    if (self.ghhaiku.userIsEditing==NO)
    {
         self.textView.text = @"";
    }
    else
    {
        self.textView.text = self.ghhaiku.text;
    }
    [self.view addSubview:self.textView];
}
```

Basically, the first time this method is called the user has to tap on `self.textView` for the keyboard to appear, and I want the keyboard to appear automatically when the method is called, like it is on subsequent calls of this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the code

```
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder]
```

**after** you have put the text view into the controller's view.

Answer (score 2):

Hope to help you

```
[textField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) 
                withObject:nil 
                afterDelay:0.2f]
```

[In iOS 6, -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] doesn't work in -viewWillAppear:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13479997/in-ios-6-uitextfield-becomefirstresponder-doesnt-work-in-viewwillappear) (comment to question by https://stackoverflow.com/users/1162777/anton)

Answer (score 0):

Try following line when you want to active the textView.

```
[self.textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Comment: That line is already in the code--just after the lazy instantiation of self.textView.  Should I put it somewhere else?

Comment: Allocate the textView first & then used the above line of code when you want to active the textView.

Comment: Hmm.  I want the textView to activate whenever this method is called.  Forgive me if I'm misunderstanding, but I just tried allocating the textView in `viewDidLoad` so that it would already be there when this method was called (and I wanted the keyboard to appear), but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: use the above code & try to activate the textView after adding it & let me know your feedback.

Answer (score -1):

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0 animations:^{
        [self addSubview:textview];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [textview becomeFirstResponder];
    }];
```